# proper way of designing controller for an MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a simple model with menu and menuItem which both inherit from an abstract class.

I have created an adminController which can do CRUD operations.

which I've stuck here is that should create controller for menu and menuItem?
because both menu and menuItem are both inherit from a same type.
meanwhile their corresonding views for a method like `Edit()` can have different appearance. 
I mean I have to check in views to know I'm trying to Edit Menu or MenuItem

but if I implement controller for each entity, I have duplicate code. 
so what is the best approach for designing controller for this kind of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, controllers are just classes, which means they can be inherited from. So, you can simply do:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    // all the actions here
}

public class MenuItemController : MenuController
{
}
```

Based on the naming conventions, then, you can apply different views to the actions per controller simply by putting them in their respective view directories: "Menu" and "MenuItem", respectively.

If you need to change a particular action method in the subclassed controller, just make the action virtual in `MenuController` and then override it in `MenuItemController`:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult SomeActionToOverride() { ... }
}

public class MenuItemController : MenuController
{
    public override ActionResult SomeActionToOverride() { ... }
}
```

This is all just basic OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, unfortunately, is "It Depends".

You could dispatch to different views based on the object type, from the same Menu controller, with the common operations on the controller, with the views calling the same HttpPost actions with a type-discriminating property. This is a design which exposes the OO architecture to the public API surface.

Or, as these are separate domain entities, you could expose two controllers with their own suite of CRUD operations and have a more REST like API surface.

Duplicate code to provide independent endpoints or security policy differentiation at what amounts to a public API surface is less of a smell than elsewhere.

Comment: a point to mention: user must edit a menu to be able edit its menuItems. so I think it's strange to have a route like */menuItem/Edit . all of menuItem CRUD operation are related its menu.

Comment: A route like /menu/Id/item/Edit makes sense for REST but not a default ASP.Net MVC route... Thus the "which way do you want to organize your API" focus of my answer.